# Grouping values when only all values are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to group some data. This is the situation:

[image]

I'm doing this select:

```
select
       min(id) id
      ,week
      ,percentage
from table1  
group by week,percentage
```

Could anyone help me out? I want that it only groups if all values are equal. If there is some different value in percentage it should not be grouping.. the id3 should not group for the week 3. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "all values are equal"?  Your results seem to be correct.  I don't get the rules for your desired results . . . except for `where id <> 2`.

Comment: the resut you get  is correct for group by  week, percentage  .. so you should expalin better your question  ..

Comment: I think you got the right result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I mean when the week and percentage before are also the same for the IDS that I'm grouping. The the result I expect(the one in the middle). for example the values for ID 1 and 2 are all the same, but for Id 3 aren't, so for the week 3 it should not group it.

Comment: Please also always include the version of SQL Server you use, especially if it's one no longer in mainstream support. Readers will assume you're on a sensibly modern version if you don't specify.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, sorry, already changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want aggregation.  You want to remove certain ids.

The following concatenates all the week/percentage values together to get a single identifier to identify duplicates.  Despite what I just said, this then uses aggregation for "filtering" to get the first one:

```
select min(id) as id, week, percentage
from (select t1.*,
             string_agg(concat(week, ':', percentage), ',') within group (order by week) over (partition by id) as id_week_percentages
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
group by id_week_percentages, week, percentage;
```

The aggregation just allows this to be written without an extra subquery.  You could do something similar as:

```
select top (1) with ties id, week, percentage
from (select t1.*,
             string_agg(concat(week, ':', percentage), ',') within group (order by week) over (partition by id) as id_week_percentages
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
order by row_number() over (partition by id_week_percentages, week, percentage order by id);
```

Or use a separate subquery to pull the first id for each week/percentage combination.

EDIT:

With `for xml path`:

```
select top (1) with ties id, week, percentage
from (select t1.*,
              (select concat(week, ':', percentage, ',')
               from table1 tt1
               where tt1.id = t1.id
               order by week, percentage
               for xml path ('')
              ) as id_week_percentages
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
order by row_number() over (partition by id_week_percentages, week, percentage order by id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is the string_agg is for sql server 2017 or later.. and I'm using the the 2012 version.

Comment: @lesiano . . . You can do essentially the same thing with `for xml path`.

Comment: I'm trying to do with the for xml path but I'm not getting it. could you help me please? I changed it to: `select top (1) with ties id, week, percentage
from (select t1.*,(select   concat(week, ':',percentage ) 
    within group (order by week)
     over (partition by id)   FOR xml path) as id_week_percentages
      from table1 t1   ) t1
order by row_number() over (partition by id_week_percentages, week, percentage order by id)`